# Basic RNN cost function not converging to zero

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

I'm writing a basic RNN.

My function for generating the hidden state is:

```
tanh(xU + sW)
```

Where **x** is the input vector and **s** is the previous hidden state vector. **U** and **W** are both the parameters that are being adjusted during backprop.

For modifying **U** and **W** I use:

```
 U += 1/(cosh^2(xU+sW)) * x * expectedValue * stepSize
 W += 1/(cosh^2(xU+sW)) * s * expectedValue * stepSize
```

Where **stepSize** is about 0.01, though I've tested lots of smaller values. The **expectedValue** is the same for both and it is just the value of the function I am trying to learn for testing.

For the cost function to determine how close my estimations are, I am using the mean squared error function:

```
1/n * (expectedValue^2 - predictedValue^2)
```

My cost function is not converging to zero over 10,000,000 iterations. Am I screwing up some of the math somewhere?

Comment: There is a better forum for this question, namely CrossValidated.SE (the SO of statistics and machine learning). You also need to provide the source code for your work so they will be able to debug it. How many times do you unroll during training? Are you using Back-Propagation Through Time? What's your batch size? These and others are questions one may expect to be asked of you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll transfer it over to that SO

Answer (score 0):

It could be the gradient vanishing problem. Try RELU activation function instead of tanh().

Comment: Would that be a problem even if I'm back-propagating every iteration? My understanding was vanishing gradient only became a problem with BPTT